# Re-Grouping of items without re-rendering and without UNMOUNTING all the children using React?

Tags: reactjs

I have this structure currently:

```
state = {
    groups: ["one","two","three"],
    rows: {
    "one": [1,11,111], 
    "two": [2,22,222], 
    "three":[3,33,333]
    }
   }
```

I am rendering this list with two nested maps.

```
{this.state.groups.map(key=> {
  return (
  <div key={key}>
      <div>{key}</div>
      {this.state.rows[key].map(el=><ChildElement key={el} el={el}/>)}
  </div>
)
})}
```

My goal is to be able to change grouping WITHOUT UNMOUNTING the children components, since they have'nt changed.
So the new state would be:

```
state = {
  groups: ["oneA","twoB","threeC"],
  rows: {
   "oneA": [1,22,111], 
   "twoB": [3,11,222], 
   "threeC":[2,33,333]
   }
}
```

Note: ChildrenComponents are very complex UI components, and whenever I regroup them, re-rendering takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to structure state, so the ChildrenComponents are not rerendered ?

Comment: use `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle to prevent re-rendering

Comment: @AmilaDulanjana shouldComponentUpdate works in case of child is not unmounted.
In my case children are Unmounted